# Button Elements as Tabs

Tags: html, button, tabs, accessibility, wai-aria

Is it okay to use `<button>` elements (rather than anchor links) as tabs?

Here's my use-case...

I'm marking up a set of tabs using button elements, and when I try to assign them ARIA roles, I get this validation error:

[image]

It appears that the ARIA role `tab` is not allowed on `<button>` elements. Is there a reason you shouldn't use `<button>` for tabs?

In case it's helpful, here's the relevant markup:

```
<menu type="list" label="Tabs" role="tablist">
    <button id="tab-1" role="tab" aria-controls="panel-1" aria-selected="true" tabindex="0">Tab 1</button>
    <button id="tab-2" role="tab" aria-controls="panel-2" aria-selected="false" tabindex="-1">Tab 2</button>
</menu>

<section id="panel-1" role="tabpanel" aria-labelledby="tab-1" aria-hidden="false">...</section>
<section id="panel-2" role="tabpanel" aria-labelledby="tab-2" aria-hidden="true">...</section>
```

Comment: See: http://www.karlgroves.com/2013/05/14/links-are-not-buttons-neither-are-divs-and-spans/ and http://webaim.org/search/?q=link+vs+button&scope=archives

Comment: *Why* do you want to use `button` instead of `a`?

Comment: Ryan - thanks for the great links, the Karl Groves one especially is excellent.

Comment: Unor - Hyperlinks define a target destination, but clicking a tab doesn't take the user anywhere. Clicking a tab performs an action -- revealing hidden content -- which makes a button the better choice IMO.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Button and Tab are in different parts of the [role hierarchy](http://w3.org/WAI/PF/aria/rdf_model.svg):

- Button is part of the command interface
- Tab is part of the sectionhead interface